# Is it redundant to use df.copy() when writing a function for feature engineering?

Tags: python, feature-engineering

I'm wondering if there's any benefit to writing this pattern

```
def feature_eng(df):
  df1 = df.copy()
  ...
  return df1
```

as opposed to this pattern

```
def feature_eng(df):
  ...
  return df
```

Comment: Depends on what happens in `...`. There might be explicit or implicit copying operations and/or (re)assignments in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say you have a raw dataframe `df_raw` and you create `df_feature` using `feature_eng`. Your second method will overwrite `df_raw` when calling `df_feature = feature_eng(df_raw)` while the first method will not. So in case you want to keep `df_raw` as it is and not modify it, the first pattern will lead to the correct result.

A little example:

```
def feature_eng1(df):
    df.drop(columns=['INDEX'], inplace=True)
    return df

def feature_eng2(df):
    df1 = df.copy()
    df1.drop(columns=['INDEX'], inplace=True)
    return df1

df_feature = feature_eng1(df_raw)
```

Here df_raw will not contain the contain the column `INDEX` while using `feature_eng2` it would.

Comment: Great explanation, especially the ‘will overwrite’ statement.  My brain hadn’t twigged until I read this.  Thanks!